# C# Find non matching values in DataTables

Tags: c#, datatable, matching, relation

I'm struggling with the following problem:

There are 2 DataTables (SSFE and FE in my case).
FE will contain items that match with SSFE, but it will also contain values not present in SSFE.

For Example

SSFE 1,2,3,4,5,6,9,10

FE   1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11

The ouput I need is in this example : 7, 8, 11.

I'm using the following code to find items that do match:

```
        DataSet set = new DataSet();
        //wrap the tables in a DataSet.
        set.Tables.Add(SSFEData);
        set.Tables.Add(FEData);

        //Creates a ForeignKey like Join between two tables.
        //Table1 will be the parent. Table2 will be the child.
        DataRelation relation = new DataRelation("IdJoin", SSFEData.Columns[0], FEData.Columns[0], false);

        //Have the DataSet perform the join.
        set.Relations.Add(relation);

        //Loop through table1 without using LINQ.
        for (int i = 0; i < SSFEData.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            //If any rows in Table2 have the same Id as the current row in Table1
            if (SSFEData.Rows[i].GetChildRows(relation).Length > 0)
            {
                SSFEData.Rows[i]["PackageError"] = SSFEData.Rows[i].GetChildRows(relation)[0][1];
                SSFEData.Rows[i]["SaleError"] = SSFEData.Rows[i].GetChildRows(relation)[0][2];
            }
        }
```

There should be an trick to find these items that do not have an relation.

Any suggestion will be great!

Comment: I suggest you use Linq - See this example: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397894.aspx - Establishing a relation will help you find common rows not different ones.

Comment: If your data is coming from a database then an Outer Join would do this

Comment: The problem is that the data is coming from 2 different servers. And I am unable to create an link between them (company policcy). Therefore I have to do this comparision in code

Comment: I have done something similar using 'Select Where Not In'. I wrote a SQL Server function that turned a CSV into a list. Then query one table, create the CSV string with the result and pass it as a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you could of course use a little bit of LINQ by turning the data tables into `IEnumerables` using the [`AsEnumerable()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatableextensions.asenumerable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)<sup>1</sup> extension method.

I am using a few assumptions to illustrate this:

1. "id" is the column with an integer value relating rows in `FEData` and `SSFEData`.
2. "id" is the primary key column on both  `FEData` and `SSFEData`.

Then this will return a list of rows from `FEData` that are not present in  `SSFEData`:

```
var notInSSFEData = FEData.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(x => SSFEData.Rows.Find((object)x.Field<int>("id")) == null)
    .ToList();
```

If assumption 2 above does not hold (i.e. the "id" field is not the primary key), a slightly more elaborate query is required.

```
var notInSSFEData = FEData.AsEnumerable()
    .Where(x1 => !SSFEData.AsEnumerable().Any(x2 => x2.Field<int>("id") == x1.Field<int>("id")))
    .ToList();
```

<sup>1</sup> this requires adding a reference to `System.Data.DataSetExtensions` (in System.Data.DataSetExtensions.dll).

Comment: That would work perfectly if the Datatables both had an primary key, this is not the case, unfortunately. I could remove duplicates from the FEData, because duplicates will not be relevant for this table. I'll report back with results

Comment: @RobinVanCleef if they don't have id as a primary key, you should use the second snippet: `.Where(x1 => !SSFEData.AsEnumerable().Any(...)`